# ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validate'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

I'm trying to do:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate
```

as mentioned [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html#the-cross-validate-function-and-multiple-metric-evaluation).
But get the error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'cross_validate'
```

Everything else in Sklearn seems to work fine, it's just this bit. Error even occurs when I run this one line and nothing else.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`cross-validate`  is new in version 0.19.0 ([change log](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html#version-0-19)):

> Cross validation is now able to return the results from multiple
>   metric evaluations. The new model_selection.cross_validate can return
>   many scores on the test data as well as training set performance and
>   timings, and we have extended the scoring and refit parameters for
>   grid/randomized search to handle multiple metrics.

In order to use it update your scikit-learn installation with either `conda upgrade scikit-learn`  if you are using conda, or `pip install --upgrade scikit-learn`. If updating is not possible, you can still use [`cross_val_score`](http://scikit-learn.org/0.18/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html#sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score)  instead.

Comment: @radtek I've upgraded now without any issues. It imports correctly on my Ubuntu machine (Python 3.6 / sklearn 0.20)

Comment: It didn't for me on python 3.7.0 on osx, scikit-learn 0.20.0.. downgrading to 0.19.0 fixed it.

Comment: In 0.19 I also see the deprecation warnings `/share/virtualenvs/ud120-projects-Jg_0faAa/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/cross_validation.py:41: DeprecationWarning: This module was deprecated in version 0.18 in favor of the model_selection module into which all the refactored classes and functions are moved. Also note that the interface of the new CV iterators are different from that of this module. This module will be removed in 0.20.
  "This module will be removed in 0.20.", DeprecationWarning)`

Comment: @radtek How are you importing it? The message implies you are importing from another module.

Comment: sklearn is installed in my virtualenv, and import is `from sklearn import cross_validation`. This is part of an ML lesson repo, not mine. Just needed to get it to work and using release 0.19 does the trick.

Comment: Yes, you are supposed to use `from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate` as it was mentioned in the post.

Answer (score 11):

On the latest stable version, 0.20.0, it is located underneath `model_selection`.

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

Refer [Documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split)

Comment: `train_test_split` is not the same thing as `cross_validate`

Answer (score 1):

from sklearn.model_selection import cross_validate

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.